# Include User Custom Functions Best Practice in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am a newbie in Symfony2 and I can't understand where I should make includes with my custom cross-projects functions (e.g. `array_merge_overwrite`, `array_last`, etc.)? I use both types of apps: web (MVC) and console (extends `ContainerAwareCommand`).

Or there is another "right way" for this?

Comment: Similar question with good answer [Symfony2 global functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336401/symfony2-global-functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and put your common functionality in it. For example, you can name it `ArrayService` and register it in the container as `array.service`. You can then access this service from controllers via

```
$this->get('array.service');
```

and from commands via

```
$this->getContainer()->get('array.service');
```

So, your code will look something like this:

```
$element = $this->get('array.service')->last($array); // or ->arrayLast($array)
```

If you need the same functionality across several projects, make a bundle with that service and add it to the `deps` file of each project. Then it will be installed when you run the `bin/vendors install` script.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your functions to static methods of some class to make them autoloadable. Or... well... Place them where you want and require() from where you need them every time.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Symfony doesn't provide a solution for the problem, and I should use **require** every way/script I use Symfony, is it so?

Comment: @MingalevME Yes, if you still on procedural programming in 2011. Try to switch to OOP.