# Symfony2 global functions

Tags: php, symfony

For example i have algorithmic function, which calculates specific hash-code. Function itself is 300+ lines of code. I need to use that functions many times in many different controllers in my bundle. Where can i store my `calculate_hash()` to use it in my bundle ? Can i access it from other bundles ? 
Can i also write global `calculate_hash()` which have access to **entity manager** ?

Didn't find my answer [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html).

Comment: But here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the Symfony2 world, this is clearly belonging to a service. Services are in fact normal classes that are tied to the dependency injection container. You can inject them the dependencies you need. For example, say your class where the function `calculate_hash` is located is `AlgorithmicHelper`. The service holds "global" functions. You define your class something like this:

```
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Helper;

// Correct use statements here ...

class AlgorithmicHelper {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function calculate_hash() {
        // Do what you need, $this->entityManager holds a reference to your entity manager
    }
}
```

This class then needs to be made aware to symfony dependecy container. For this, you define you service in the `app/config/config.yml` files by adding a `service` section like this:

```
services:
  acme.helper.algorithmic:
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Helper\AlgorithmicHelper
    arguments:
      entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Just below the service, is the service id. It is used to retrieve your service in the controllers for example. After, you specify the class of the service and then, the arguments to pass to the constructor of the class. The `@` notation means pass a reference to the service with id `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

Then, in your controller, you do something like this to retrieve the service and used it:

```
$helper = $this->get('acme.helper.algorithmic');
$helper-> calculate_hash();
```

Note that the result of the call to `$this->get('acme.helper.algorithmic')` will always return the same instance of the helper. This means that, by default, service are unique. It is like having a singleton class.

For further details, I invite you to read the Symfony2 [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html). Check those links also

1. The service container [section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) from Symfony2 book.
2. An answer I gave on accesing service outside controllers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127711/697930).

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: You've called the method `test_method()`. This makes me think it's somthing to do with unit testing, but as far as I can tell, it isn't. Can you either edit your answer and call it `example_method()` or something, or if this is about unit testing, where do you put the method you want to use/test?

Comment: I called it `test_function()` because the original poster did name his algorithmic method `test_function()`. It is not related to unit testing, but it could, if the algorithm is to be use in unit tests. If I change the function name, I would need to edit original question so it is in sync with the new naming.

Comment: Good point, I feel really stupid now :-). I'm going to take the liberty of just renaming everything to `calculate_hash()`

Comment: Hehe nothing stupid here, I often read the answer, and forgot to read the associated question :) Ok, no problem with the renaming.

Comment: how can we make this on symfony 3?

Answer (score 1):

Braian in comment asked for Symfony 3 answer, so here is one **Symfony 3.3** (released May 2017):

#### 1. The original class remains the same

```
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Helper;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

final class AlgorithmicHelper
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function calculateHash()
    {
        // Do what you need, $this->entityManager holds a reference to your entity manager
    }
}
```

#### 2. Service registration [is much simpler](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults: autowire # this enabled constructor autowiring for all registered services

    Acme\AcmeBundle\Helper\AlgorithmicHelper: ~
```

#### 3. Use constructor injection to get the service

```
use Acme\AcmeBundle\Helper\AlgorithmicHelper;

class SomeController
{
    /**
     * @var AlgorithmicHelper
     */
    private $algorithmicHelper;

    public function __construct(AlgorithmicHelper $algorithmicHelper)  
    {
        $this->algorithmicHelper = $algorithmicHelper;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        // some code
        $hash = $this->algorithmicHelper->calculateHash();
        // some code
    }
}
```

You can read about Symfony 3.3 dependency injection (in this case registering services in config and using it in controller) news in these 2 posts:

- https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/
- https://symfony.com/blog/the-new-symfony-3-3-service-configuration-changes-explained

Comment: This should have been an answer to a separate question. You are allowed to ask and answer your own questions. In fact, since there are no votes on this answer, I would suggest making a new question and copying this answer to it, then deleting the answer here. Once this is done, you can leave a comment pointing the user to the new question and answer.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: You gave the reason yourself in the first sentence: "Braian in comment asked for Symfony 3 answer". So they asked a new question in a comment that you answered here, even though the question is specific to Symfony2.

Comment: I think it's trend and better to use 1 question over many version, rather than create a new own question + answer to that version for each version.

For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901256/how-do-i-read-from-parameters-yml-in-a-controller-in-symfony2

The main goal is not about Symfony 2, even though it might seem to, but how to "get that working in Symfony of version that was new in time of asking that question".