# How do I read from parameters.yml in a controller in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I have put a couple of custom variables in my app/config/parameters.yml.

```
parameters:
    api_pass: apipass
    api_user: apiuser
```

I need to access these from my controller, and have tried to fetch them with

```
$this->get('api_user');
```

from within my controller file. When I try this, I get this error message:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "api_user".
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

In **Symfony 2.6 and older versions**, to get a parameter in a controller - you should get the container first, and then - the needed parameter.

```
$this->container->getParameter('api_user');
```

This [documentation chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-container-parameters) explains it.

While `$this->get()` method in a controller will load a service ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#accessing-other-services))

In **Symfony 2.7 and newer versions**, to get a parameter in a controller you can use the following:

```
$this->getParameter('api_user');
```

Comment: Note that the `get` method in the controller uses the container too, but it can only get services from a container, not parameters. You need `getParameter` to get parameters.

Comment: When I try `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('api_user');` I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method ..Longpath..\Controller::getContainer().

Comment: @Bohr sorry, different version of Symfony2. I've edited my answer - check it now ;)

Comment: The URL for documentation is now http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html

Comment: Symfony 2.7 and newer: `$this->hasParameter()` not working yet.

Comment: You can upgrade this instantly with Rector now: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/pull/333

Answer (score 32):

## The Clean Way - 2018+, Symfony 3.4+

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3 + 3.4** there is much cleaner way - easy to setup and use.

Instead of using container and service/parameter locator anti-pattern, you can **pass parameters to class via it's constructor**. Don't worry, it's not time-demanding work, but rather *setup once & forget* approach.

How to set it up in 2 steps?

#### 1. `app/config/services.yml`

```
# config.yml

# config.yml
parameters:
    api_pass: 'secret_password'
    api_user: 'my_name'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        bind:
            $apiPass: '%api_pass%'
            $apiUser: '%api_user%'

    App\:
        resource: ..
```

### 2. Any `Controller`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

final class ApiController extends SymfonyController
{
    /**
     * @var string 
     */
    private $apiPass;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiUser;

    public function __construct(string $apiPass, string $apiUser)
    {
        $this->apiPass = $apiPass;
        $this->apiUser = $apiUser;
    }

    public function registerAction(): void
    {
        var_dump($this->apiPass); // "secret_password"
        var_dump($this->apiUser); // "my_name"
    }
}
```

### Instant Upgrade Ready!

In case you use older approach, you can [automate it with Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/pull/333).

## Read More

This is called **constructor injection over services locator** approach.

To read more about this, check my post [How to Get Parameter in Symfony Controller the Clean Way](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/01/22/how-to-get-parameter-in-symfony-controller-the-clean-way).

(It's tested and I keep it updated for new Symfony major version (5, 6...)).

Comment: New minimalistic way on this topic: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/11/05/do-you-autowire-services-in-symfony-you-can-autowire-parameters-too/

Answer (score 12):

I send you an example with swiftmailer:

### parameters.yml

```
recipients: [email1, email2, email3]
```

### services:

```
your_service_name:
        class: your_namespace
        arguments: ["%recipients%"]
```

### the class of the service:

```
protected $recipients;

public function __construct($recipients)
{
    $this->recipients = $recipients;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In Symfony 4, you can use the `ParameterBagInterface`:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params->get('parameter_name');
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in `app/config/services.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

It works for me in both controller and form classes. [More details can be found in the Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service).

Comment: Passing whole parameters bag is like passing a whole container. It makes sense only in "if some particular service needs lots of container parameters" (quoted from the post)

Comment: so ,are you mean passing whole parameter cause problem in  performance?

Comment: That's one of reasons, but mostly for readability. If I see parameter name `$meetupApiKey` I know what to expect slightly better than in `$parameterBag`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   dump( $this->getParameter('api_user'));
}
```

For more information I recommend you read the doc :

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/parameters.html

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 5 when your Controller extends `AbstractController` you can use :

```
$projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters for more info

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 4.3.1 I use this:

**services.yaml**

```
HTTP_USERNAME: 'admin'
HTTP_PASSWORD: 'password123'
```

**FrontController.php**

```
$username = $this->container->getParameter('HTTP_USERNAME');
$password = $this->container->getParameter('HTTP_PASSWORD');
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 4.8. Are you sure it worked someday?

Comment: I really forgot about this but yes it probably worked cause I post only tested stuff!

Comment: Sorry, Acharaf. I don't know, but didn't work in my controller.
Inside your controller you can call getParameter directly, with no DI. I.e.: `$this->getParameter('foo')`. That's what I did to make it work in SF 4.8.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
$container->getParameter('api_user');
```

Visit http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html