# symfony 4 : How to get "/public" from RootDir

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5

I have an image under the `public` folder.
How can I get my image directory in symfony4 ?
In symfony 3, it's equivalent is :

```
$webPath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/';
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read from parameters.yml in a controller in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901256/how-do-i-read-from-parameters-yml-in-a-controller-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use either

```
$webPath = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir() . '/public/';
```

Or the parameter `%kernel.project_dir%`

```
$container->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/';
```

Comment: Worth to mention that the controller needs to extend the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller class, not the abstract one that you find on most examples Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController

Comment: worth to mention @CarlosDelgado that the controller class you mentioned is being deprecated in Symfony 4.2 `@deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use {@see AbstractController} instead.`

Answer (score 36):

**It is a bad practice** to inject the whole `container`, just to access parameters, if you are not in a controller. Just auto wire the `ParameterBagInterface` like this,

```
protected $parameterBag;

public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
{
    $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;

}
```

and then access your parameter like this (in this case the project directory),

```
$this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir');
```

Hope someone will find this helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

In Controller (also with inheriting AbstractController):

```
$projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
```

Comment: Why did you downvote this? This is the only one that worked for me?!

Comment: @godrar because we're talking about Symfony 4 where your controllers should be defined as services thus, not inheriting from AbstractController.

Comment: @vdavid Yes, it worked in old versions. In the new version you do not have access to the kernel in this way (inject "container" is bad practice)

Answer (score 7):

In config/services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    webDir: '%env(DOCUMENT_ROOT)%'
```

In your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

...

public function yourFunction(Parameterbag $parameterBag)
{
   $webPath = $parameterBag->get('webDir')
}
```

If you need to access a directory within public, change the last line to the following:

```
$webPath = $parameterBag->get('webDir') . '/your/path/from/the/public/dir/'
```

Comment: Moving forward to Symfony 4 and beyond, this is closer to the real answer.  $this->get('kernel') is deprecated in 4.2.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that uses an environment variable instead of hard coding the public directory. Although, I would recommend binding this as an argument for the service in its config instead of injecting the whole parameter bag.

Answer (score 5):

You can inject `KernelInterface` to the service or whatever and then get the project directory with `$kernel->getProjectDir()`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class Foo
{
    protected $projectDir;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->projectDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
    }

    public function showProjectDir()
    {
        echo "This is the project directory: " . $this->projectDir;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from **Symfony 4.3** we can generate absolute (and relative) URLs for a given path by using the two methods `getAbsoluteUrl()` and `getRelativePath()` of the new `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UrlHelper` class.

[New in Symfony 4.3: URL Helper](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-url-helper)

```
public function someControllerAction(UrlHelper $urlHelper)
{
    // ...
    return [
        'avatar' => $urlHelper->getAbsoluteUrl($user->avatar()->path()),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers seems valid, but I think it's simplier if you configure it as parameter in `services.yaml`

If you need to use it in serveral services, you can bind it like this:

```yaml
# services.yaml

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    bind:
      $publicDir: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
```

```php
# src/Services/MyService.php

class MyService
{
    public function __construct(
         private string $publicDir,
    ) {
    }

    // …
}
```

This way, this is configured at one place only, and if later you decide to change `/public` to something else, you will have to change it only in .yaml file.

If you don't need the root directory but a subdirectory, it might be better to define the final target path: This way you will be more flexible if you need later to move only that directory, like `$imageDir` or `$imagePath` (depends if you will use the full directory or only the public path).

Note also the default `public` path is defined in `composer.json` file, in the `extra.public-dir` key