# Symfony 3.4 - Autowire not working for bind values?

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4` and would like to autowire / auto inject the value of the `%kernel.environment%` parameter into a controller action.

However binding the parameter to a argument name does not work:

```
// app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false        

        bind:
            $kernelEnvironment: '%kernel.environment%'

        MyBundle\:
            resource: '../../src/MyBundle/*'
            exclude: '../../src/MyBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

        MyBundle\Controller\:
            resource: '../../src/MyBundle/Controller'
            tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


// src/MyBundle/SomeController.php
public function showPostAction($kernelEnvironment, $post_id) {
    ...
}
```

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Controller "MyBundle\Controller\SomeController::showPostAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$kernelEnvironment" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one."

**Why does this not work?**

I know that I could specify `MyBundle\Controller\SomeController` directly within in the `services.yml` and set the value of `$kernelEnvironment` in the arguments list. However this solution would mean that I would have to specify the argument for every controller that uses this parameter. This is is not what autorwire is good for. Binding the argument should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: I assume that the binding doesn't work for controllers, because they would like to handle them as route parameters. However try this in your controller to get this parameter: `$this->getParameter('%kernel.environment%')`

Comment: For 3.4 you cannot use bind for controller actions, only constructor arguments.  Bind works fine in 4.x.  Just one of those things. A somewhat verbose discussion (and example) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009230/read-from-parameters-in-symfony-3-4-getparameter-null/54024701#54024701).

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the hint. This seems to be the solution. However the limitations of bindings to constructors seems to be only true for parameters. Other bindings work well (e.g. $translator: '@translator.default'). If you add this info as answer I would accept it.

Comment: Yep.  Only for parameters for some reason.  Services seem to work just fine.  Go figure.  I kind of think this is basically a duplicate question.  Feel free to up vote the linked answer if you want.