# Best way to create global function in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know what is the best way to create a global function in Symfony 3.

I'll provide an example: On my website, you can subscribe to the newsletter. When you do, it sends you an email to thank you. The user can do this on many pages.

So I would like to create it once, and use the `sending mail function` in all the controllers that need it.

Do I have to create it as a class in the app, or do I have to create a bundle specially for it?

I found this answer, but not sure it's the best: [Symfony2 global functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336401/symfony2-global-functions)

Comment: I would definitely stick the the answer to the question you linked to. My general rule is to have a service if the function has any (at all) dependency to other functionalities (e.g. other services) and if it does not then utility function {{public static function}} would do just fine.

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer that I needed, thanks you !
Does it matter to have a lot a service, even if they all do 1 or 2 functions ? Or is it better to create one which contains all functions ?

Comment: @DesTunk It is better to have a lot of services with few responsabilities. You will improve your code testability et maintainability.
Exemple: NewsletterMailSender  UserProvider COmmandValidator ....

Comment: @Destunk: The services are instantiated on the fly, so up until you actually use it, the number of services (memory consumption wise) is not relevant. But, I agree with goto, you should probably have many smaller services with their own responsibility...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do it is [Services and Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html). Just create the service you need and either inject it into controller or use `$this->get('your.service.name')->...` in controller.